sizeof(va_list) = 24 not 8
By definition, in stdarg.h typedef char* va_list.so the size of va_list should be 8 not 24 in ubuntu 20.04 64bits gcc 9.4.0, i don't know why i get the size of va_list is 24?
I runed the following codes:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
void print_num( int count, ...){
        va_list args;
        printf("sizeof(args):%d\n",sizeof(va_list));
        va_start(args,count);
        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
//            printf("*args = %d\n",va_arg(args,int));
              printf("*args = %d\n",*(int*)args);
              args += 4;
        }
        va_end(args);
}
int main(){
        print_num(5,1,2,3,4,5);
        return 0;
}

i expected printf 1 2 3 4 5 but i get an error:change_function.c:13:8: error: assignment to expression with array type 13 |   args += 4;
so i used the following method to print，but i don't know why the above code can get an error?
i guess the source of the question is the type of the va_list. I would appreciate it if you could help me.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
void print_num( int count, ...){
        va_list args;
        printf("sizeof(args):%d\n",sizeof(va_list));
        va_start(args,count);
        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
                printf("*args = %d\n",va_arg(args,int));
//              printf("*args = %d\n",*(int*)args);


//      args += 4;
        }
        va_end(args);
}
int main(){
        print_num(5,1,2,3,4,5);
        return 0;
}

Thank you!!!

Why should va_list be an alias for char *? Where did you read that? It could be anything the compiler needs or wants. And the arguments might not be passed as you think, don't make assumptions and try to process varargs function arguments unless you know the exact implementation of the compiler.

Unrelated: %d is not the correct conversion specifier for sizeof(va_list) so both programs have undefined behavior.

The result you are getting conflicts with your assumption. That means your assumptions is just invalid. No, va list is not a pointer to char. No, you cant just "args +=4". I do not understand what do you expect. why i get the size of va_list is 24? why not? Is the number suprising?

I don't know where you found this definition for va_list, but the error message clearly indicates that that bit of code is not compiled, probably due to some conditional compilation. If you're on a typical Linux system, you could look at man va_begin.

thank you , i find the definition of va_list in stdarg.h get the following code typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;  typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;  it depends on gcc complier __builtin_va_list

Then your source stdarg.h might be invalid or might be not used for the actual compilation.


why i get the size of va_list is 24?

You are most probably on x86_64 architecture using standard abi. From https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf page 53 valist is given as:
typedef struct {
unsigned int gp_offset;
unsigned int fp_offset;
void *overflow_arg_area;
void *reg_save_area;
} va_list[1]

From page 12 the type unsigned int has 4 bytes, and a pointer on 64bit architecture has 64 bits so 8 bytes. So size of va_list on your architecture with this compiler and compiler options using that application binary interface is 4+4+8+8 = 24.
Additionally, that document around pages 51-53 explains how variadic arguments are passed. For float values special floating point registers are used, which makes the "args += 4" method not possible to work on this abi.

It's pretty cool.  I think i understand the problem by your answer. Thank you !
